# Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am attempting to upload file to s3 from a php script following a tutorial I found on YouTube

I have the following php files

upload.php

```
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

require 'start.php';

if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $file=$_FILES['file'];

    $name = $file['name'];
    $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'];

    $file_ext = explode('.', $name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $key = md5(uniqid());
    $tmp_file_name = "{$key}.{$file_ext}";
    $tmp_file_path = "../files/{$tmp_file_name}";

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $tmp_file_path);
    try{
        $s3 -> putObject([
                'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],
                'Key' => 'uploads/{$key}.{$name}',
                'Body' => fopen($tmp_file_path, 'rb'),
                'ACL' => 'public-read'

        ]);

        unlink($tmp_file_path);
    }catch(S3Exception $e){
        die("Error uploading file");
    }


}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">

            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Start.php

'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1'
        ]);
    ?>

config.php

```
<?php

return [
    's3' => [
        'bucket' => 'umnbucket2016'
    ]
];
?>
```

My file at ~/.aws/credentials contain a [default] and than my key and secret key

When I attempt to upload a file I get the following error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out [file] /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php [line] 282)' in /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php:79 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(199): Aws\Credentials\InstanceProfileProvider->Aws\Credentials\{closure}(Array) #1 /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(152): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(2, Array, Array) #2 /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(60): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}() #3 /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(240): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true) #4 /var/www/html/AWS in /var/www/html/AWS/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php on line 79
```

I originally had the config.php store my key and secret ID but changed that in favor of the credentials file

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is running on an EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is a clue:

> fopen(http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/):
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out

The library is attempting to access the security credentials metadata, but is getting a timeout.

Can you confirm that that URL can be opened from inside the instance? This code should be on a working AWS instance of course, and the metadata URLs should be accessible.

There may be some issue causing that URL to be blocked. Firewall?  Security Groups?